# Hive - Not a valid ORC file After merge

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc

I have a table with ORC (transaction is true and zlib compression)
Paritioned by a column called `pdate`.

Im trying to merge this table with another table.

```
merge into source_t using target_t
on source_t.id=target_t.id WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
col=col1,
col2=col2
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT VALUES 
( target_t.id,
target_t.name,
'20190715');
```

**20190715** - its my partition, Im giving this manually. During the first time merge no issues. But after running the merge second time, Im not able to query the data in that table.

```
hive> select * from source_t   limit 1;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.orc.FileFormatException: Not a valid ORC file
Time taken: 0.093 seconds
hive>
```